# EnableAuthenticator page not found from template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I generated a new dotnet application using `dotnet new mvc --auth Individual` (dotnet 2.1.301). Then I wanted to add QR code to 2 factor authentication according to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-enable-qrcodes?view=aspnetcore-2.1) but I can't find any of those file, like **Views\Manage\EnableAuthenticator.cshtml**. But the web page has those pages, and in the project.assests.json I can see this line `Templates/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/Account.Manage.EnableAuthenticator.cshtml`.

But how to get it to my page so I can edit it and add QR code? Where are the pages located? I can browse to the page https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Manage/EnableAuthenticator withount any problem.

Comment: Identity view files are now embedded in a Razor class library in 2.1, please see the linked duplicate for more detail.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the information!